# In Angular 7, how do I change my form submit button text based on whether its a create or update?

Tags: angular, forms, button, angular7

I'm using Angular 7.  I have this component HTML for adding a simple Product object ...

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="">Product name: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" style="width: 300px" class="form-control" required
                [(ngModel)]="product.name" name="productName">
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I re-use the form if we are performing an update.  I would like to change the submit button text to read "Update" if there is a product being updated.  I figured I could check using the product's id (check if its not null) but I can't figure out how to change the button text.  This is all I have so far ...

```
<input type="submit" value="{[product.id != null ? 'Update' : 'Create']}" />
```

but this just prints the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change your value to interpolation.

```
<input type="submit" [value]="product.id !== null ? 'Update' : 'Create'" />
```

You can also do it in a button...

```
<button type="submit">{{ product.id !== null ? 'Update' : 'Create' }} </button>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps unrelated, but I'm noticing the "Create" value is getting printed for updating product pages and "Update" is printed for adding products.  Should I be checking for something other than null?  The value of the product.id for adds is "undefined".

Comment: Yes. Just check if `product.id` exists instead of against null. So {{ product.id ? .... }}